# How does torque/pbs scheduler work?

Tags: scheduler, hpc, torque

I looked online for a while and besides the source code on github, there are only tutorials on how to use torque.

Can someone give and overview of how it actually work? what are the algorithms?

I'm asking this because i'm trying to understand what is the scaling complexity, how it compares with spark/hadoop in terms of startup time of for jobs. I think these question will clarify with a basic understanding of how things work. For example, is it similar to linux's CFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Torque a scheduler is decoupled from the queue, job and process management. That means that one can run different schedulers.

The two no cost schedulers provided with Torque are

- The basic scheduler `pbs_sched` that implements a fifo with constraints.
- [MAUI](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/maui/) that implements several scheduling policies, such as fairshare, backfill based on wallclock limits, and a tunable FIFO policy.

Also read on [MOAB](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/mwm/7-0/help.htm), a commercially available scheduler for torque.

Comment: you say that MAUI is a scheduler, but from the description you make, it seems it actually also acts as a queue management (FIFO,..). Is there also another queue management module in TORQUE?

Comment: @RockScience MAUI is a pluggable scheduler. The management of the queue (job insertion, deletion, assignment of job IDs) is performed by the PBS server component. I missed the word "_policy_" in my description. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you for the precision, that makes it very clear now. From your experience, how responsive is the queue? (ie how long is the delay between the task trigger and the actual start of the execution?)

Comment: Thre responsiveness decreases with the growth of a number of jobs in the queue and the number of nodes. There are several tunable parameters for the queue server and the schedulers that can help on large clusters. Using a PBS Pro scheduler with 100k jobs in a queue and 200 nodes I have seen each scheduling iteration take up to 600 seconds. So I would not bet on fastest possible startup time with Torque without tuning.